# Is it useful to maintain file and folder permission in a Backup copy, using rSync?

Tags: backup, rsync

i'm using rsync to make a backup copy of an HFS+ partition (mac filesystem).
I'm wondering if is it useful to maintain file and folder permission when i do a backup copy.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is will be VERY useful, when/if you'll need to restore from backup.

Comment: I think it would depend on what's being backed up.  If it's just a bunch of JPG files or Office documents, probably not so much.  The OP needs to give more information, though the default of "preserve permissions/ownership" is a reasonable one.

Comment: @cjc If those JPGs/DOCXs are only meant to be accessed/edited by specific user/groups, the permission are *very* important.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @kondybas.

Some programs will break if you restore the files/folders with different owner/permissions. So, it will be really necessary to backup/restore files with their original permissions such as config files.